# Exporting Panel setting to a Feature

Tags: panels, features

Does anyone know how to add the **Panels** > **Settings** > **General** > **'Make all views available as panes'** checkbox to a feature?

I guessed the Strongarm box but I don't see the setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. ctools_content_all_views was being used in a Panopoly feature so I had to learn how to use the Features Override module.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's variable and it's in the Strongarm box. His name is ctools_content_all_views. It can be not set by default - then just submit your form and check again.

Comment: I'm not seeing ctools_content_all_views as a choice in the Strongarm list. Any ideas why not?

Comment: Did you submitted form on page  Panels > Settings > General?

Comment: yes, I resubmitted the form and checked to make sure ctools_content_all_views is not being used by other features

Answer (score 0):

If you are using strongarm then check node/%/node is unable then `page_manager_node_view_disabled` is set to false